# Как сделать что бы item в menu был с левой стороны, а не с правой?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Есть `menu`, как сделать, что бы первый `item` был с левой стороны экрана, а не с правой?

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:title="Back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_sync"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_done"
        android:title="@string/done_pref"
        android:showAsAction="always" >
    </item>

</menu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С левой стороны чего?

Comment: с левой стороны экрана

Comment: не уж то местами item'ы хотите поменять o_O

Comment: А, пардон, у Вас же картинка есть.

Comment: @ermak0ff Эм, сейчас оба item находятся с правой стороны, как сделать что бы первый item был с левой стороны экрана, а второй с правой?

Comment: @Lucky_girl да, теперь вопрос понятен.

Comment: скорее всего без использования Toolbar'а не обойтись, вы же наверно юзаете ActionBar?

Comment: хотя можно попробовать ваш `ic_action_sync` использовать вместо ic_logo

Comment: @ermak0ff тут сейчас используется ActionBarSherlock (да, это очень старый проект), а если нужно что бы было и ic_logo и item слева, то только через Toolbar?

Comment: @Lucky_girl ну эт уже надо смотреть насколько `ActionBarSherlock` поддается кастомизации...

Comment: в шерлоке это можно сделать через кастомную вьюшку `setCustomView()`